# How to ping the load balancer ip address from Virtual machine in azure

Tags: azure

I have created a internal load balancer in azure and backend pool configured two vm's health probe and rule also configured, If I browse the Load balance ip it work fine but while i'm checking the ping request from the VM to Load balancer it shows time out error. Is it possible to make a successful ping request.

Answer (score 2):

Not only ICMP, any traffic from backend VM to frontend IP of internal load balancer will not work. This is one of the limitation of azure internal load balancer.

- Bhuvanesh Kumar Kumaresan, Cloud Solution Architect

Answer (score 1):

Regular icmp traffic is not allowed on Azure load balancers, you should either try a port ping (psping), telnet, nmap, nc, or other utilities to check E2E connectivity.

Some extra details here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/e9e53e84-a978-46f5-a657-f31da7e4bbe1/icmp-outbound-ping-on-azure-vm